# Как мне проверить, что даты из одного диапазона пересекаются с другим диапазоном дат?

Tags: java

Всем привет!
У меня есть следующая задача: есть активы (компьютер, принтер и тд), которые пользователи могут резервировать под собой в конкретные даты. Естественно, даты резервирований не должны между собой никак пересекаться. Я написал метод, который принимает множество активов и проверяемую дату. Если дата не пересекается с датами из других резервирований, то я разрешаю пользователю резервировать под собой актив на эту дату. Если же совпадает с датами хоть у одного резервирования, то выбрасываю пользователю ошибку, что дата занята. Дело в том, что мой метод сейчас работает некорректно. Для примера, если Вася зарезервировал за собой актив с 27 по 27 октября 2022 года, то Петя сможет зарезервировать этот же актив с 26 по 28 октября, что неправильно. 27 октября же входит в диапазон с 26 по 28 октября, а значит эта дата уже занята.

Вот метод, который мне удалось реализовать:

```
public boolean isDateWithinRangeAssetReservations(Set<Asset> assets, Date checkDate) {

        Date checkDateWithTruncate = DateUtils.truncate(checkDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        String query = "select e from am_AssetReservation e where e.refAsset IN :assets and (:checkDate between e.dateFrom and e.dateTo) and e.isActive = true";
        List<AssetReservation> assetReservations = dataManager.load(AssetReservation.class)
                .query(query)
                .parameter("assets", assets)
                .parameter("checkDate", checkDateWithTruncate)
                .list();
        return !assetReservations.isEmpty();
    }
```

Он частично работает, но покрывает не все возможно варианты. Как мне его реализовать корректно?

Answer (score 0):

Допустим есть некий существующий диапазон existing с определенными значения dateFrom и dateTo и необходимо проверить диапазон checked на пересечение. Тогда условие будет следующим:
checked.dateFrom > existing.dateTo and checked.dateTo < existing.dateFrom
Думаю адаптировать его под ваш SQL будет несложно.

Comment: Добрый день! Под SQL пока не получилось адаптировать, но ранее сравнивал даты нового резервирования с датами текущих резервирований с помощью if-else. 

                    _&& (checkDateWithTruncate.after(assetReservation.getDateTo()) && checkDateWithTruncate.before(assetReservation.getDateFrom()))_) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

Добавил условие, которое вы указали (выделено курсивом) - все равно не работает как нужно. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так вы сравниваете дату с диапазоном, а надо диапазон с диапазоном.